# Angularjs custom service method that returns a boolean value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

One of my controllers has problems talking to one of my services in Angularjs :

1. The user enters a code;
2. The controller takes the entered code and passes it to my custom service to know if the code is valid or not, via a method called IsCodeValid;
3. That service method makes a call to a web api method that returns true if the code is valid, otherwise false;
4. The service method returns the result of the web api call (true if valid; otherwise false);

Here is (part of) my controller :

```
angular.module('clockin').controller('KeypadController', ['$scope', '$location', 'userService',
        function ($scope, $location, userService) {

            ...

            $scope.keypadEnter = function () {
                var result = userService.isCodeValid($scope.code);
                console.log(result);
            };

            ...
  }]);
```

Here is my Service :

```
angular.module('clockin').service('userService', ['$http',
    function ($http) {
        this.isCodeValid = function (code) {
            $http.get("/api/clockin/iscodevalid?code=" + code)
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result;
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

My web API method works perfectly. If I call it manually and specify a valid code as a parameter into the URL, it returns true as expected.

The controller, however, always gets false as a result, even if a valid code is entered.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http.get cal is an asynchrnous call. So you wont get the expected result like this.

$http.get call returns a promise which when resolved call a callback function that you have specified in your then method.

**Solution:**

In your service method return the promise object like this

```
angular.module('clockin')
  .service('userService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.isCodeValid = function (code) {
      return $http.get("/api/clockin/iscodevalid?code=" + code);
    };
  }]);
```

In your controller wait for promise to get resolved for getting the result

```
$scope.populatekeypadEnter = function () {
  var result = userService.isCodeValid($scope.code)
    .then(function (result) {
      $scope.keypadEnter = result;
    });                
};
```

You can also use .success function instead of then, to register the callback method.
You can refer this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks @coder ! I can now get it to work using a promise. The only thing is that, back into the controller, the result is an object, not a simple boolean value. Do I have to parse the http.get() result in the service to return only the bool value ?

Comment: and your service returns boolean and not object ?

Comment: I just needed to use JSON.parse on the result because my service sends a raw boolean value. I could have wrapped it in an object but I prefer parsing the boolean value in client side.